# How can I make the object to rotate only once 360 degrees?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now it's rotating twice 360 degrees.
I want it to rotate 360 degrees but only once when clicking with the mouse button.

```
private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (isRotating == false)
            StartCoroutine(Rotate(5));
    }
```

And

```
IEnumerator Rotate(float duration)
{
    Quaternion startRot = transform.rotation;
    float t = 0.0f;
    while (t < duration)
    {
        isRotating = true;
        t += Time.deltaTime;

        transform.rotation = startRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(t / duration * 360f, Vector3.up);

        yield return null;
    }
    transform.rotation = startRot;

    isRotating = false;
}
```

Comment: it looks correct to me, can you try `t / duration * 180f` and see if that "works"? Also make sure to use a `Debug.Log("starting rotation")` to check if you are accidentally calling that function twice. But I doubt that, because you have the `isRotating` bool to check that... How long do 2 rotations take? 5 seconds?